# Git merge, but adding in all the conflicting lines

Tags: git, go

`code.go` on branch `main` currently contains:

```
package code

some Golang code() {
}
```

`code.go` on branch `new-branch` currently has:

```
package code

some other Golang code() {
}

even more code() {
}
```

Ideally, I want the end result to be:

```
package code

some Golang code() {
}

some other Golang code() {
}

even more code() {
}
```

How can I "merge" the `new-branch` onto `main` to achieve the above result? When I merge, `git` gave me conflict, since `some Golang code()` and `some other Golangcode()` are on the same line between branches.

If I choose "Accept both incoming," one of my brace goes missing, resulting in syntax error. I simply want the resulting `code.go` file to contain all those 3 block of codes in their intact form.

Comment: For me, I do it manually and I don't know if there is an easier way, so you can Compare Changes (on vscode) and copy the code from the new branch and accept the main branch then past copied code which is gonna be the function.

You can use git diff command to see and compare changes, or use vscode Compare Changes, or use GitHub Desktop to make it easier and notice the changes

Comment: Note that "accept both incoming" is part of your IDE, *not* part of Git. There is a form of merge called *union merge*, and `git merge-file` even supports it, but it's not generally suitable here and you should just do this particular merge "by hand" anyway. At most, when using Git (not some IDE), you might invoke `git merge-file --union` on the three input files and manually adjust the result.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that there is no way for git to determine which code should go first: moving the `some Golang code` to the end instead would be just as natural as having it at the beginning. So doing the merge by hand is the way to go, so that you can make sure the code ends up in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You *will not be* do it automatically, because you have here "classic" conflict (I show it here in GUI, but internally Git see the same thing): one line of code *replaced by another snippet*

[image: Diff of files]

You must to perform manual merge and resolve conflict by hand using any (good) merge-tool, supported by Git

Answer (score 0):

> If I choose "Accept both incoming," one of my brace goes missing, resulting in syntax error. I simply want the resulting code.go file to contain all those 3 block of codes in their intact form.

Unfortunately, the merge algorithms used by git and other common VCSes are not "code aware", they are operating only on the level of *text*.

So, while it is obvious to *you* which lines belong together, an automated tool has to try and guess which lines should go where with no idea what they mean. To see things from the tool's point of view, keep the structure of the files but replace the words and punctuation with nonsense:

```
habble hibble

quig quag quog blib-blob frong
gnorf
```

and

```
habble hibble

quig quaggledy quog blib-blob frong
gnorf

quoogle quog blib-blob frong
gnorf
```

The merge algorithm sees that the two branches have added different text at lines 3, 6, and 7, but both have "gnorf" at line 4. So it assumes that's the same "gnorf", and gives you something like this:

```
habble hibble

quig quag quog blib-blob frong
quig quaggledy quog blib-blob frong
gnorf

quoogle quog blib-blob frong
gnorf
```

The algorithm could be *less* clever, and not look for cases where you've added the same code in both branches, but this would be wrong just as often.